# Checkbox Parameters Retrieval in Python/Flask Application Using a Loop

Tags: python, sql, list, for-loop, flask

I have a Python/Flask code that executes two SQL queries :

```
def valeurs_thematiques():
    query_thematiques = """
    SELECT NOMTHEMATIQUE
    FROM THEMATIQUES
    """
    connection = connect(path)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query_thematiques)
    res_them = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    return res_them
res_them=valeurs_thematiques()

def valeurs_activites():
    query_activites = """
    SELECT NOMTHEMATIQUE
    FROM THEMATIQUES
    """
    connection = connect(path)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query_activites)
    res_act = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    return res_act
res_act=valeurs_activites()


@app.route('/formulaire_creat_congres')
def formulaire_creat_congres():
    return render_template('formulaire_creat_congres.html', res_them=res_them, res_act=res_act)
```

Then, I have an HTML page with a loop that displays the results of the query in checkbox inputs :

```
   <table>
               <tr>
                <td colspan="2" >
                    <label><strong>Thématiques :</strong></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                {% for t in res_them %}
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ t[0] }}" name="nomtheme" value="{{ t[0] }}">
                        <label for="{{ t[0] }}">{{ {t[0]} }}</label>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            
         
        </table>
        
         <table>
                   <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" >
                        <label><strong>Activités :</strong></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    {% for a in res_act %}
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ a[0] }}" value="{{ a[0] }}" name="nomactivite">
                            <label for="{{ a[0] }}">{{ a[0] }}</label>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

             
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Ajouter"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The results of the queries are displayed correctly on the '/formulaire_creat_congres' page.

I want to retrieve the checkbox parameters with nomtheme=request.args.getlist("nomtheme"). However, when I display the value of the variable nomtheme, I either get an empty list or the list: ['on', 'on'] :

```
@app.route('/confirmation_creat_congres', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def confirmation_creat_congres():
    if request.method=='GET':
        codcongres = request.args.get("codcongres")
        titrecongres = request.args.get("titrecongres")
        numedition = request.args.get("numedition")
        date_debut_c = request.args.get("date_debut_c")
        date_fin_c = request.args.get("date_fin_c")
        URL = request.args.get("URL")
        nomtheme = request.args.getlist('nomtheme')        
        nomactivite = request.args.getlist("nomactivite")
        
        # codcongres=codcongres,titrecongres=titrecongres, numedition=numedition,
        #date_debut_c=date_debut_c, date-fin_c=date_fin_c, URL=URL, 
nomtheme=nomtheme,nomactivite=nomactivite 
    else :
        codcongres = request.form.get("codcongres")
        titrecongres = request.form.get("titrecongres")
        numedition = request.form.get("numedition")
        date_debut_c = request.form.get("date_debut_c")
        date_fin_c = request.form.get("date_fin_c")
        URL = request.form.get("URL")
        nomtheme = request.form.getlist("nomtheme")
        nomactivite = request.form.getlist("nomactivite")

        
    connection = connect(path)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    query11 =  """
    SELECT CODETHEMATIQUE
    FROM THEMATIQUES
    WHERE NOMTHEMATIQUE = ?
    """
    codthemes = []
    codactivites = []

    for theme in nomtheme:
        cursor.execute(query11, (theme,))
        codtheme = cursor.fetchone()
        if codtheme is not None:
            codthemes.append(codtheme)
   
    query22 =  """
    SELECT CODEACTIVITE
    FROM ACTIVITES
    WHERE NOMACTIVITE = ?
    """
    for activite in nomactivite:
        cursor.execute(query22, (activite,))
        codactivite = cursor.fetchone()
        if codactivite is not None:
            codactivites.append(codactivite)
    
    query = """
    INSERT INTO congres (CODCONGRES, TITRECONGRES, NUMEDITIONCONGRES, DTDEBUTCONGRES, DTFINCONGRES, URLSITEWEBCONGRES)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """
    query1 =  """
    INSERT INTO TRAITER (CODCONGRES, CODETHEMATIQUE)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    """
    
    
    query2 =  """
    INSERT INTO PROPOSER (CODEACTIVITE, CODCONGRES)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    """
 

    
    cursor.execute(query, (codcongres,titrecongres,numedition,date_debut_c,date_fin_c,URL))
    connection.commit()
    
    for codtheme1 in codthemes:
        cursor.execute(query1, (codcongres, codtheme1))
    for codactivite1 in codactivites :
        cursor.execute(query2,(codactivite1, codcongres))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    message="La création d'un nouveau congrès est réussie ! "
    
    print("Requête HTTP :", request.url)
    print("Valeurs de nomtheme :", nomtheme)

    
    return render_template('confirmation_creat_congres.html', message=message, nomtheme=nomtheme)
```

It should contain the results of the previous query that have been checked (checkbox input).

Comment: It would help if you showed the values of `res_them` and `res_act` from the first code sample.

Comment: **res_them :**  [('Comptabilité-Contrôle',), ('Ressources Humaines',), ('Marketing',), ('Finance',), ("Gestion des Systèmes d'Information",), ('Gestion de projets informatiques',), ('Business Intelligence',), ('Informatique Décisionnelle',), ('Veille stratégique',)]

**res_act :** [('Visite guidée de la ville',), ('Repas de gala',), ('Repas rencontre',)]